# Third level of CSS Dropdown Menu not showing when mouse point on it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I found out some bugs in this template regarding Drop Down Menu issues:

1 - Third level menu only will show up if mouse pointer point outside the area of 2nd level menu.

2 - Third level menu will keep flashing when mouse pointer move around in Third level menu area.

website: http://ggbestworld.blogspot.com

**CSS Code:**

```
#main-top {
padding: 0 30px;
position: relative;
}

#main-top .main-top-left {
background: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-JEZl1PMDYo8/UYtjykAgWaI/AAAAAAAAFtY/ND01RKL4rPA/s60/main-top-boxed-light-left.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 60px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 30px;
}

#main-top .main-top-right {
background: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-TnI3BPLsLiU/UYtjzoTF-cI/AAAAAAAAFrY/yxkF14BLCRU/s60/main-top-boxed-light-right.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 30px;
}

#main-top .main-top-middle {
background: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NFrvbTMMStw/UYtjyyqk4kI/AAAAAAAAFrQ/Vf5E3lp2e-I/s60/main-top-boxed-light-middle.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 60px;
}

#menu-wrapper {
position: relative;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark {
margin: -57px 13px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-left {
height: 57px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 17px;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-right {
height: 57px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 17px;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-middle {
height: 57px;
margin: 0 17px;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu a {
display: block;
font-family: Arial,Helevtica,Verdana,san-serif;
font-size: 11px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 100%;
padding: 20px 15px 17px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu ul {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 1px 1px;
margin: 49px 0 0;
padding: 8px 0;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-left {
background: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ly-FrHHkF-s/UYtj0Bds3UI/AAAAAAAAFs4/I4-SVHralkQ/s228/menu-flip-dark.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-right {
background: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ly-FrHHkF-s/UYtj0Bds3UI/AAAAAAAAFs4/I4-SVHralkQ/s228/menu-flip-dark.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -114px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu-middle {
background: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ly-FrHHkF-s/UYtj0Bds3UI/AAAAAAAAFs4/I4-SVHralkQ/s228/menu-flip-dark.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -57px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu a:hover {
    background: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ly-FrHHkF-s/UYtj0Bds3UI/AAAAAAAAFs4/I4-SVHralkQ/s228/menu-flip-dark.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -171px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#main-menu .flip-dark #search-trigger {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PGNhVMEi2-8/UYtj07YhSOI/AAAAAAAAFrk/ZiWyLpI720Y/s60/search-popup-trigger-dark.png");
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu, #main-menu .flip-dark .menu li {
    float: left;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu li li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    padding: 13px 12px 11px;
}
#main-menu .flip-dark .menu li li a:hover {
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#main-menu .flip-dark .menu a {
    color: #EAEAEA;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
#main-menu .flip-dark .menu li li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#main-menu .flip-dark .menu ul {
    background-color: #282828;
    border-color: #000000;
}
#main-menu .flip-dark .menu li li a:hover {
    background-color: #313131;
}
#main-menu .menu, #main-menu .menu * {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
#main-menu .menu {
    line-height: 1;
}

#main-menu .menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
    width: 225px;
}
#main-menu .menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
#main-menu .menu li:hover {
    visibility: inherit;
}
#main-menu .menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu .menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu .menu li:hover ul, #main-menu .menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#main-menu .menu li li:hover ul, #main-menu .menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 225px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#main-menu .menu a.with-ul {
    min-width: 1px;
    padding-right: 2.25em;
}
.sub-indicator {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    top: 1.05em;
    width: 10px;
}
a > .sub-indicator {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
    display: none;
    top: 20px;
}
a:focus > .sub-indicator, a:hover > .sub-indicator, a:active > .sub-indicator, li:hover > a > .sub-indicator, li.sfHover > a > .sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px -100px;
}
#main-menu .menu ul a > .sub-indicator {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.shadow ul {
    padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
}
.shadow ul.shadow-off {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#main-menu .menu li:hover li ul, ul#main-menu .menu li.sfHover li ul, #main-menu .menu li li:hover li ul, #main-menu .menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -999em;
}
#main-menu .menu ul .sub-indicator, #main-menu .menu ul a:focus > .sub-indicator, #main-menu .menu ul a:hover > .sub-indicator, #main-menu .menu ul a:active > .sub-indicator, #main-menu .menu ul li:hover > a > .sub-indicator, #main-menu .menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px 0;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id='menu-wrapper'>
 <div id='main-top'>
 <div class='main-top-left'/>
 <div class='main-top-right'/>
 <div class='main-top-middle'/>
 </div>
 <div id='main-menu'>
 <div class='flip-dark' id='menu-inner'>
 <div class='menu-left'> </div>
 <div class='menu-middle'>
 <div class='menu-middle-inner'>
 <ul class='menu' id='menu-main-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sidebar Layouts</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Full Width Page</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sidebar Right</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sidebar Left</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Double Sidebars</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Double Right Sidebars</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Double Left Sidebars</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sample Layouts</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Business Homepage #1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Business Homepage #2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Business Homepage #3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Business Homepage #4</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Classic Magazine #1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Classic Magazine #2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Design Agency</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Portfolio Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Showcase Blogger</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>The Orman</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>The McAlister</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>The WebTreats Special</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Features</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Contact Forms</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Layout Builder</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Lightbox Integration</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Portfolios</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Responsive Design</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Shortcodes</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Columns</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Display Posts</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>HTML Elements</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Icons</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sliders</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Tabs and Toggles</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Slider Manager</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Total Control</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Content Options</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Font Control</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Footer Options</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Options</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Typography</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Unlimited Sidebars</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Page Templates</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Archives</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post List</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Grid</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Grid &#8211; 2 Columns</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Grid &#8211; 3 Columns</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Grid &#8211; 4 Columns</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Post Grid &#8211; 5 Columns</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sitemap</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Redirect</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I seeking some helps to fix these issues.

Thank You Very Much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this selector:

```
#main-menu .menu li:hover li ul {
  top: -999em;
}
```

That makes your third level menu be outside the visual; change this with `>` selector to make it more specific and don't affect your third level:

```
#main-menu .menu li:hover > li > ul {
  top: -999em;
}
```